# Is there any respected you in English?

Tags: word-usage

In almost every Dravidian language, there are two versions of you, one is friendly version and another one is a  respect version.

Is there any respected version of you in English?

Comment: I'm going to boil down the duplicate question for you: The form of "you" used in English ***is*** the formal form. It's the informal version "thou" that has fallen out of everyday usage.